# OnClickListener crashes app

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm learning android development. I created a simple layout consisting of a button (id:button1). I added an OnClickListener to this button, which when clicked, shows the next page (layout). There  appears to be no errors in the code, but when I run it, it simply crashes. I tried it using android 2.3.3 and 2.2 emulators, but no success. when I comment out the onclicklistener part, the app runs. 
i searched through various sites and questions, but no success.
Here is the java code:

```
package com.sid.next;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class mySplash extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.sid.next.SHOWMENU"));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Edit1:**
 [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/NU3uikWk)

**Edit2:** [main.xml](http://pastebin.com/G0dnpB0T)

**Edit3: [*solved*!] i didn't have any contentview set for the myMenu.java activity. Thanks anyways!**

edit4: changed **android.R.id.button1** to **R.id.button1**

Comment: How about posting the stacktrace?

Comment: how to do that? i'm new to eclipse/java.

Comment: hi, what is "SHOWMENU"? Activity & class???

Comment: it refers to the activity/class called myMenu.java

Comment: you should post the content of main.xml

Comment: `android.R.id.button1` need change to `R.id.button1`

Comment: [solved!] i didn't have any contentview set for the myMenu.java activity. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay. so finally i figured it out myself!
i hadn't set any contentView for the myMenu.java class.

also changed **android.R.id.button1** to **R.id.button1**. (credit: Imran Rana)

thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

By:

```
 final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

That is replace **android.R** by **R**.

Comment: [solved!] i didn't have any contentview set for the myMenu.java activity. Thanks anyways!

Comment: i'm using **R**. **android.R** gave problems. the app never started at that time. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `SHOWMENU` is an Activity then do Declare in Manifest File.

By the given data i think this is your option remaining.

```
<activity
        android:name=".SHOWMENU"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Add inside the `<application >  </application>` Tags in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Just copy and paste in your xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sid.next.SHOWMENU"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.sid.next.SHOWMENU"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

Comment: i've already done that
here is my manifest file:
'<activity
            android:name=".myMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sid.next.SHOWMENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>'

Comment: Why dont you simple start the activity by calling
 startActivity(new Intent(mySplash.this, myMenu.class));

Comment: @me.sid : Just copy and paste in your manifest file. http://pastebin.com/CsVmggWQ

Comment: basically you've removed the intent-filter.
anyways, i tried doing that but it still crashes when the button is clicked.

Comment: [solved!] i didn't have any contentview set for the myMenu.java activity. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Rathter calling activity this way

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.sid.next.SHOWMENU"));
```

try this way

```
Intent g = new Intent(new Intent(mySplash .this, SHOWMENU.class));
            startActivity(g);
```

Comment: it crashes when the button is clicked.

Comment: 05-11 13:08:50.136: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 13:08:50.136: E/AndroidRuntime(401):      at com.sid.next.mySplash.onCreate(mySplash.java:17) the logcat suggets the error is at line number 17 of you code the button id might be incorrect and  the way you were using will give error like 05-11 14:07:44.708: E/AndroidRuntime(559): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=the.sense.image.Informatin }

Comment: [solved!] i didn't have any contentview set for the myMenu.java activity. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(new Intent(CURRENT_SCREEN_NAME.this, NEXT_SCREEN_NAME.class));
startActivity(i);
```

and don't forget to write this in manifest below the activity.

```
<activity android:name=".NEXT_SCREEN_NAME" ></activity>
```

Comment: if next activity is not defined in manifest app will crash when you click button.

Comment: [solved!] i didn't have any contentview set for the myMenu.java activity. Thanks anyways!